# How to calculate the energy harnessed by going over a speed bump?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, spring

Recently, I've been reading about how some startups are using technology to harness kinetic energy when a car goes over a speed bump. Obviously, the speed that the car is going and the weight of the car would play a role in determining just how much energy is generated. But, I'm not exactly sure how. Does anyone know the formula for calculating the energy?

Comment: The speed shouldn't matter (in simple terms) just the weight of the car times  the distance it compresses the bump

Comment: I’m able to figure out the kinetic energy quite easily. But, my understanding is that when the energy is applied as input to the turbine, about 40% of it is lost. So, at best, the turbine would only be able to generate about 60% of the kinetic energy of the car, right?

Comment: You don't need a turbine. You would probably use electric linear motor/generators for the dampers so you would generate electricity directly at high efficiency. You could then also use this for active suspension. I don't think you will recover a significant amount of energy though and I won't be investing in these startups :)

Comment: The details depend on the overall design. The physics of it is that a compressed spring stores potential energy which is then released when the spring relaxes. How energy is diverted from the spring to another device depends on design details. I am voting to close this question as it lacks sufficient details to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple model the speed bump is just a spring, the weight of the car compresses it by a certain amount.

Energy = force (weight) * compression  distance.

Although the car will be slowed down by the process because the energy needed to climb up the speed bump ultimately comes from the kinetic energy of the car, the speed of the car doesn't affect the amount of energy extracted. At least in a simple calculation - in practice suspension reaction and the pitching motion of the car will change with speed.

If you know the speed of the car before and after, then that does give you the energy input into the system. That multiplied by the efficiency of the process gives you the energy collected.

Comment: Is the weight measured in kilograms and the compression distance in meters? Also, is the energy in this equation in joules?

Comment: weight in Newtons and distance in metres gives energy in Joules

Comment: I think if you hit the speed bump faster the springs will compress more and more rapidly and more energy will be absorbed by the dampers (which is the energy the startups are thinking about trying to recover).